# Propery way to call ActiveX CAB file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, activex

I was able to create my cab file using the guide given by MSDN(forgot the link). It works perfectly using html but not in aspx. Can someone pls show me the proper way to call the cab file in my aspx page.

HTML CODE:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <object id="ActiveX" classid="clsid:6E139A7C-AF68-4557-A124-119E6F13689B" codebase="DemoCSharpActiveX.cab"></object>
</head>
```

ASPX CODE:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
 <object id="ActiveX" classid="clsid:6E139A7C-AF68-4557-A124-119E6F13689B" codebase="DemoCSharpActiveX.cab"></object> 
</head>
```

note: the asp webform, html and cab file is in the same folder

Comment: What do you expect the ASP.Net engine to do with your `<head>` element server-side?

Comment: i dont really have an idea to run it on asp.net so can you pls help me on this.

Comment: Remove the `runat` attribute.

Comment: i was able to successfully use the activex.cab builtin factions via javascript but not working in asp

Comment: still im getting the error after removing the runat :(

Comment: "still im getting the error after removing the runat " - ok, how do you expect everyone else to know what "does not work perfectly" means for you? Consider adding information about errors (and post actual HTML produced by ASPX too).